# How to use "Format Text" tab on ribbon and context menu for VSTO RichTextBox

Tags: outlook, vsto, richtextbox, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I've added a `RichTextBox` control to an **Outlook Form Region** as in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163403.aspx#S5). The problem is that there are no controls to edit the text size, color, etc. I just figured that the default context menu and ribbon would work with the `RichTextBox` control, but apparently I was mistaken.

What has to be done to hook these up? Is it even possible? If not, what other options are available?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can hook the existing Formatting tab in the ribbon to your custom RichTextBox, however you can easily add your own ribbon tab, and make controls for these. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh128768#Ribbon).

Another alternative could be to add your own ribbon style panel just above your RichTextBox, to make it more obvious to the user that those are the editing tools for that RTB.